# "2016-09-07T13:00:00.000Z" could not find date format

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

I have date in NSString as `2016-09-07T13:00:00.000Z`

I could not convert it to `NSDate`.

I tried below `NSDateFormatter` code,

```
 NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];    
 dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss";            
 NSLog(@"Date: %@",[dateFormatter dateFromString:self.newsArticle.release_date]);
```

Please give me some guide.

Comment: `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZZ`. Also, set the formatter's `locale` to `en_US_POSIX` as outlined in Apple Technical Q&A 1480 (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1480/_index.html).

Comment: what date you want

Comment: No just wanted simple date, then I will convert it to my required format, like 12 Sep, 2016 like.

Comment: Thanks @Rob, it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your date formate to `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'`.

```
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'";
NSLog(@"Date: %@",[dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2016-09-07T13:00:00.000'Z'"]);
```

Comment: Could you tell me, what is the meaning of sss ?

Comment: @ArpitParekh Sry i haven't check your comment. Rahul is right for that.